# Insert second slide with Lyx and Beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations, lyx-layouts

I am trying to create a presentation in LyX using Beamer. I am using LyX 2.1.0. I created a new document, and selected `Document -> Settings -> Document Class -> Presentations -> Beamer`.

Then, I tried to add a new slide using the LyX section selector.

I selected `Frame`. This allowed me to create the first frame, give it a title, and write the content for the first frame. However, I can't work out how to insert the second frame. Or rather, I can't work out how to end the first frame which would then allow me to start the next frame.

How do you create multiple Beamer slides in LyX 2.1.0?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (Edit -> Start new environment) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Edit -> Start new parent environment), depending on whether you are in an environment inside the frame or not.

These are shortcuts that insert a Separator environment and start a new frame.

This is described in Help --> Specific Manuals -> Beamer Presentations.

[image]

Comment: Holy cow that has lots of crap. What's the idea of NOT inserting the separator with `Frame` command right away? I lost 50% of my last 10% of 10 hairs on my head because of this.

Comment: I actually overlooked the Beamer help file. If you are still wondering basic questions, it is a MUST that you check out the Beamer Introduction at `Help -> Specific Manuals -> Beamer Presentations`. At the end of the document, you can also find the link to the more advanced documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A slide or Frame in LyX consists of a Frame heading followed by contents and then a separator. So first select the Frame tag from the drop down list and give it a title Then fill in the Contents of the Frame and in the end select a separator from the drop down list at the top right corner. You can repeat this process to create as many slides/Frames as you like.

Here is a beginner's Video about starting a Presentation in LyX using the Beamer Class. Hope this helps you out. [Beginners Presentation with LyX using Beamer](https://youtu.be/n5CWv7vFtcc?list=PLJn3oPuoFR0d1HHf5hhrMjFLlJQMF9yXg)