# How to end block in beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx

Hey I try to do presentation in beamer but I have problem with blocks. I start new Frame and I create new block. But when I click double enter I dont go out from this block. How can I end block and write sth in normal style?

Comment: Does it do what you want if you change the "layout" combo box to "standard" or "frame"?

Comment: When I change to standard then I am still in Block and when I change to frame I do antoher frame in frame. I also dont have "separator" :( I found solution that I have to click alt+p+enter to begin new block or new frame and then I have to change this new block to  "standard" to get the result which I want but it is impractical

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185335/90297

Comment: @Math122 I suggest you make a feature request on https://www.lyx.org/trac. We've changed the Beamer interface a few years ago and we're still smoothing some things out.